# How to pass optional parameters in Perl? (For a beginner)

Tags: perl, subroutine

I've read http://www.perl101.org/subroutines.html but I just don't understand optional parameters.

I want to call the [following sub](https://metacpan.org/source/SSIMMS/PDF-API2-2.033/lib/PDF/API2/Content.pm#L2020) in [PDF::API2](https://metacpan.org/pod/PDF::API2). The doc says "-indent" is an option. How exactly do I pass a parameter for indent of 20?

This is what I'm passing at the moment:

```
$txt->section($str, $contentwidth,$heightmax);
```

This is the sub

> ```
> sub section {
>     my ($self,$text,$width,$height,%opts)=@_;
>     my $overflow = '';
>
>     foreach my $para (split(/\n/,$text)) {
>         if(length($overflow) > 0) {
>             $overflow .= "\n" . $para;
>             next;
>         }
>         ($para,$height) = $self->paragraph($para,$width,$height,%opts);
>         $overflow .= $para if (length($para) > 0);
>     }
>     if (wantarray) {
>         return ($overflow,$height);
>     }
>     return $overflow;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> my ($self, $text, $width, $height, %opts) = @_;
> ```

The `%opts` gives it away. You need to pass a list of key and value pairs. It's not a reference though, just additional values that are optional.

The `$self` gets inserted by Perl for you. Then you've got the three mandatory parameters that you already pass. After that, it's options.

```
$obj->section( $text, $width, $height, -indent => 1 );
```

The way those options are assigned to `%opts` will slurp all the remaining arguments after the height into that hash and will be passed through to `$self->paragraph` later on.

Just make sure it's always pairs of values.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Borodin. I wrote this at night from my phone.

Comment: @vanHoesel your edit was actually not bad. I'll take up some of it. Thanks.

Comment: Great, thanks! I didn't realise the hyphen was supposed to be in there as well.

Comment: @Yvonne that's a valuable lesson learned here. In programming every character matters. There is no approximation. Things are either correct or they are not. Most of the time it's a semicolon that is missing, but this kind of thing here is easy harder to track down, especially when your language is as forgiving as Perl is. :-)